# scipy-numba erfc complex number using error

Tags: python, scipy, numba, complex-numbers

I am trying to write a function which part of it make a complex number and then calculate the erfc of that number to be used to calculate wofz function in numba scipy. The reason for this is that numba scipy does not support wofz function, so I should use erfc function to reproduce it. But I realized it seems that erfc cannot work with complex number, when I put a real number it works well, but when using a simple complex number I got following error. Thanks in advance for any help.

here is the function:

```
@njit(parallel=True)
def faster(first,Hz, DRM, vpec,velaxis, bh, h1f, nh):
    t1=np.zeros(2048)
    t4=np.zeros(2048)
    t5=np.zeros(2048)
    for i in range(2048):
        va=0
        va1=0
        va1_new=0
        

   
        for j in range(i-100, i+100):
            if j<0:
                ne=2048+j
                veldif=(i-j)*Hz*DRM - (vpec[ls,ne])
                
            if j>2047:
                ne=j-2048
                veldif=((i-j))*Hz*DRM*1 - (vpec[ls,ne])
            if 0<= j <=2047:
                ne=j
                veldif=velaxis[i] - (velaxis[j]+vpec[ls,j])
            powe=((veldif))/bh[ls,ne]
            u=powe
            x=u
            a=(6.265*10**8)*(1215.67*10**-13)*((4*3.14)**-1)*((bh[ls,ne])**-1)
            z = (u + 1j*a)
            zp=-1j*z
            wz1=np.exp(-a**2 -u**2)
            wz2=np.real(erfc(1.0+1j*4.9))
            wz3=wz1*wz2
            va=va+((h1f[ls,ne]*nh[ls,ne])/bh[ls,ne])*wz3
            
            va1=va1+((h1f[ls,ne]*nh[ls,ne])/bh[ls,ne])*np.exp(-u**2)


        t1[i]=i 
        t4[i]=first*va1
        # t_new[i]=first*va1_new

        t5[i]=first*va
    return(t1,t4, t5)
```

and here is the error:

```
TypingError: No implementation of function Function(<ufunc 'erfc'>) found for signature:
 
erfc(complex128)
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Overload of function 'erfc': File: numba_scipy/special/overloads.py: Line 9.
        With argument(s): '(complex128)':
       No match.

During: resolving callee type: Function(<ufunc 'erfc'>)
During:
```

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://numba-scipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/special.html) : it is explicitly stated as not supported for complex numbers (I do not use this module and found this information in less than 1 minute).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for my question, just to learn, how did you understand that it does not support complex number? do you mean this expression?
Supported signature(s): float64(float64)

I thought it only means that real and imaginary part should be in the form of float 64.

Comment: Complex numbers are not yet supported. You can implement it in the following way: https://github.com/person142/numba_special/issues/1

Comment: `float64(float64)` means a function taking 1 double-precision float and returning the same type. Complex128 number are a pair of 2x 64-bit floats. `float64` and `complex128` are two different incompatible types.

Answer (score 1):

### Complex Numbers are not supported by  scipy-numba

This is the main [issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3860#issue-420409240) for the lacking support.
But there is a portable workaround. With a small Cython-layer the function can be exposed in a way, with wich Numba can work with.

**cython_wrappers.pyx**

This function exposes an interface, where Numba can work with.

```
cimport scipy.special.cython_special as sp
cimport numpy as np

cdef api airy(  double in_real,double in_imag,
                double* out_1_real,double* out_1_imag,
                double* out_2_real,double* out_2_imag,
                double* out_3_real,double* out_3_imag,
                double* out_4_real,double* out_4_imag):
    
    cdef double complex in_,out_1,out_2,out_3,out_4
    in_.real=in_real
    in_.imag=in_imag
    
    sp.airy(in_,&out_1,&out_2,&out_3,&out_4)
    
    out_1_real[0]=out_1.real
    out_1_imag[0]=out_1.imag
    out_2_real[0]=out_2.real
    out_2_imag[0]=out_2.imag
    out_3_real[0]=out_3.real
    out_3_imag[0]=out_3.imag
    out_4_real[0]=out_4.real
    out_4_imag[0]=out_4.imag

cdef api erfc(  double in_real,double in_imag,
                double* out_real,double* out_imag):
    
    cdef double complex in_
    in_.real=in_real
    in_.imag=in_imag
    
    cdef double complex output=sp.erfc(in_)
    
    out_real[0]=output.real
    out_imag[0]=output.imag

cdef api wofz(  double in_real,double in_imag,
                double* out_real,double* out_imag):
    
    cdef double complex in_
    in_.real=in_real
    in_.imag=in_imag
    
    cdef double complex output=sp.wofz(in_)
    
    out_real[0]=output.real
    out_imag[0]=output.imag
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

#python setup.py build_ext --inplace
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(
                  "cython_wrappers.pyx", 
                  compiler_directives={'language_level' : "3"}
                  ),
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
)
```

**Numba Implementation**

```
import cython_wrappers

import ctypes
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from numba import types
from numba.extending import intrinsic,get_cython_function_address
from numba.core import cgutils

##################Intrinsics###################
@intrinsic
def val_to_double_ptr(typingctx, data):
    def impl(context, builder, signature, args):
        ptr = cgutils.alloca_once_value(builder,args[0])
        return ptr
    sig = types.CPointer(types.float64)(types.float64)
    return sig, impl

@intrinsic
def double_ptr_to_val(typingctx, data):
    def impl(context, builder, signature, args):
        val = builder.load(args[0])
        return val
    sig = types.float64(types.CPointer(types.float64))
    return sig, impl

##################Get functions###################
double = ctypes.c_double
double_p = ctypes.POINTER(double)

addr = get_cython_function_address("cython_wrappers", "airy")
functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None,double,double,
                           double_p,double_p,
                           double_p,double_p,
                           double_p,double_p,
                           double_p,double_p,)
airy_fn_complex = functype(addr)

addr = get_cython_function_address("cython_wrappers", "erfc")
functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None,double,double,
                           double_p,double_p,)
erfc_fn_complex = functype(addr)

addr = get_cython_function_address("cython_wrappers", "wofz")
functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None,double,double,
                           double_p,double_p,)
wofz_fn_complex = functype(addr)

@nb.njit("UniTuple(complex128,4)(complex128)")
def airy_complex(val):
    out_1_real_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)
    out_1_imag_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)
    out_2_real_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)
    out_2_imag_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)
    out_3_real_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)
    out_3_imag_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)
    out_4_real_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)
    out_4_imag_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)

    airy_fn_complex(np.real(val), np.imag(val),
                    out_1_real_p,out_1_imag_p,
                    out_2_real_p,out_2_imag_p,
                    out_3_real_p,out_3_imag_p,
                    out_4_real_p,out_4_imag_p,)

    out_1_real=double_ptr_to_val(out_1_real_p)
    out_1_imag=double_ptr_to_val(out_1_imag_p)
    out_2_real=double_ptr_to_val(out_2_real_p)
    out_2_imag=double_ptr_to_val(out_2_imag_p)
    out_3_real=double_ptr_to_val(out_3_real_p)
    out_3_imag=double_ptr_to_val(out_3_imag_p)
    out_4_real=double_ptr_to_val(out_4_real_p)
    out_4_imag=double_ptr_to_val(out_4_imag_p)

    return (np.complex(out_1_real + 1.j * out_1_imag),
            np.complex(out_2_real + 1.j * out_2_imag),
            np.complex(out_3_real + 1.j * out_3_imag),
            np.complex(out_4_real + 1.j * out_4_imag),)

@nb.njit("complex128(complex128)")
def erfc_complex(val):
    out_real_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)
    out_imag_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)

    erfc_fn_complex(np.real(val), np.imag(val),out_real_p,out_imag_p)

    out_real=double_ptr_to_val(out_real_p)
    out_imag=double_ptr_to_val(out_imag_p)

    return np.complex(out_real + 1.j * out_imag)

@nb.njit("complex128(complex128)")
def wofz_complex(val):
    out_real_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)
    out_imag_p=val_to_double_ptr(0.)

    wofz_fn_complex(np.real(val), np.imag(val),out_real_p,out_imag_p)

    out_real=double_ptr_to_val(out_real_p)
    out_imag=double_ptr_to_val(out_imag_p)

    return np.complex(out_real + 1.j * out_imag)
```